# Timer Jobs not running due to AllowServiceJobs and AllowContentDatabaseJobs being false

Tags: timer-jobs, 2019, timer-service

After upgrading our farm to SharePoint 2019 I have problems with some timer jobs not running at all. I was able to fix this issue yesterday by [following this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49638007/3464036). 
However during the night, the settings have been reset to `$false` for `AllowServiceJobs` and `AllowContentDatabaseJobs`. I wonder why this happens.

My best bet at the moment is that it has to do with the new min role model we introduced with the update. Our farm consists of two "Front-end with Distributed Cache" servers and two "Application with Search". The timer serice is installed and online on all four servers. AllowServiceJobs and AllowContentDatabaseJobs are true for the application servers and false for the front-ends.

Comment: Have you been able to find a solution for this? We're experiencing the same issue on SP 2016 environment.

Comment: We changed back to custom roles for the servers. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

If you're suspecting that external component is updating your Timer job service object, then you should inspect the ULS log because it is most likely that it's using SSOM to update the object.

This is the line of code which is called in `Update` method:

```
ULS.SendTraceTag(
    947417466U, 
    (ULSCatBase) ULSCat.msoulscat_WSS_ConfigCache, 
    ULSTraceLevel.Medium, 
    "Updating SPPersistedObject {0}. Version: {1} Ensure: {2}, SkipObjectCallbackCheck: {3}, HashCode: {4}, Id: {5}, Stack: {6}", 
    (object) this.ToString(), 
    (object) this.m_Version, 
    (object) this.m_EnsureOnUpdate, 
    (object) this.m_SkipObjectCallbackCheck, 
    (object) base.GetHashCode(), 
    (object) this.Id.ToString(), 
    (object) SPUtility.StackTraceString(ULSCat.msoulscat_WSS_ConfigCache, 
    ULSTraceLevel.Medium));
```

Search for the string "Updating SPPersistedObject" in ULS and locate the process/component which is responsible for the update.